# Can't get POST request to work in angular2

Tags: angular

New to angular and I can't figure this one out.
My GET functionality works perfectly, and I can send this request(http://localhost:3000/api/posts/?content=testentry) through postman and update my db.

The code below is from my services.ts sheet and I do get a log of 'server received "whatever i typed"' but that's as far as I get.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
getAllPosts() {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/posts')
    .map(res => res.json());
}

createPost(post) {
  console.log('server received ' + post);  
  let payload = new URLSearchParams();
  payload.set('content',post);
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/posts',payload.toString(), { 
    headers: headers
  }).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: do you subscribe to it somewhere?

Comment: export class AddPostComponent implements OnInit {
  id_content = "";

  constructor(private postsService: PostsService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addPost(){
  this.postsService.createPost(this.id_content).subscribe();
  console.log(this.id_content);
  }
  
}

Comment: It first logs the CreatePost's log then it logs the addpostcomponent post, both with the typed message i want entering my db.

Comment: second parameter of post method should be post to create `this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/posts',`post, { 
    headers: headers
  })`

Comment: in Observers world, if you don't subscribe it doesn't do anything, so you need to subscribe to `createpost` method
Also if your backend accepts json as post body life would be easier for you

Comment: I do subscribe to it when I call it, and when I watch on my cmd prompt, when i send a request from postman it shows the full post request, "/api/posts/?content=testentry" but when i hit the request from my page it only shows "/api/posts/.

Comment: Are you using Angular Cli? What is your dev-server port? 4200?

Comment: Everything is running on my express http server on port 3000, i can use all the functionalities; get,  post, put, delete on postman and i can obtain my get through angular. I am just so confused and I know its going to be something very silly at the root of it.

Comment: @Cbh Okey, what says the browser console on this request?

Comment: Response with status: 0  for URL: null, {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: t, …}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was all due to a silly mistake as expected. On my server side code I had: `Post.addPost(req.query.content,function(err,post)` instead of `Post.addPost(req.body.content,function(err,post)`. 
Thanks for everyone helping and taking time from your days.

Comment: Oh man I hate those kind of bug hunting situations. Had a similar problem yesterday, with a web api controller missing a pluralization. Kept getting 404s even though I could access the api.